# How do I fix missing NuGet references?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore, .net-4.6

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017, version 15.6.6.  A co-worker gave me a solution which he says I should be able to open and rebuild without any problems.  There seems to be something wrong with either the NuGet packages and/or Framework.  Co-worker will only say it must be something wrong with my computer, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

I tried right clicking on the solution and picking "Restore NuGet Packages".  The references still have the yellow triangle by them.  I tried to rebuild anyway and got the message "The reference assembilies for framework ".NETFramework, Version=v6.0" were not found.  I looked at the project properties and saw the target framework was blank.  I tried choosing .NET Framework 4.6, but that gave me multiple errors of the type "Package [name of NuGet package] is not compatible with net46(.NETFramework, Version=v4.6)."  The co-worker had mentioned trying .NET Core before, so I tried downloading .NET Core 3.1 from this site: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk.  I installed it (including restarting my computer), but don't see .NET Core in the Target framework.  Can anyone help guide me getting this solution running?

Here's an image showing the missing references (yellow triangle) on the right and the reference error message when I tried to rebuild.
[image]

Here's an image after I set the framework to 4.6 and showing the target framework choices I have available:
[image]

Comment: Seems like your collegue created a dotnet 6 (NET6) application which is simply [not supported on Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2017/vs2017-compatibility-vs#-visual-studio-2017-support-for-net-development)

Comment: Well that's good to know. VS 2017 is our standard tool so I wonder what happened.  What version do I need?  2019 maybe?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 supports NET6

Answer (score 2):

We can see [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6):

> .NET 6 is supported by Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2022 for Mac (and later versions).

You can update to VS2022 and try again.